# Why changing the operands in logical and causes different output

Tags: python, logical-operators

Leetcode 83. Remove duplicates from the sorted list
here is the code

```
    def deleteDuplicates(self, head: Optional[ListNode]) -> Optional[ListNode]:
        tmp = head
        
        while tmp and tmp.next:
            if tmp.val == tmp.next.val:
                tmp.next = tmp.next.next
            else:
                tmp = tmp.next
        return head
```

if I interchange the values in the while loops condition causes a runtime error.
`while tmp.next and tmp`

Answer (score 0):

From the type annotation I read that head can be None, it's annotated with Optional. This means `tmp = head` would set `tmp` to `None` if `head` is `None` and you would consequently call `None.next`, which raises an `AttributeError` exception and leads to a Runtime error. `tmp and tmp.next` safeguards this as `tmp.next` would never be called if `tmp` is `None`.

Answer (score 0):

`and` short-circuits.

`tmp and tmp.next` prevents `tmp.next` from being evaluated when `tmp` is `None`.

`tmp.next and tmp` does not.